# How to use TWAIN in a Powerbuilder application

Tags: powerbuilder, scanning, twain

We have a powerbuilder application and we want use a scanner through this application with the use of the TWAIN drivers.
Does anyone have previous experience or code samples about how this can be developed?

Comment: Are you trying to integrate the scanning function to a desktop app or a browser-based application?

Comment: You need a TWAIN ActiveX control to be integrated into your powerbuilder app. Just simply search in Google, and you will find several options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard (and may be impossible) to integrate TWAIN into PowerBuilder using **plain** PowerScript (without regard for possible ActiveX control).

Working solution (for me) was creation of Dll (C++) based on [TWAIN Sample code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/files/TWAIN%202%20Sample%20Application/). In brief

- PowerBuilder app creates response window (modal dialog)
- call Dll function to override window proc: SetWindowLong(handle(..), GWL_WNDPROC, MyFunction)
- and initiate TWAIN transfer.

Sample application in C++ is working. But, of course, some changes required to adopt it for PowerBuilder.